# Get Wordpress to show updates available, but not let admin install them

Tags: wordpress

We're locking down some of our WP sites and only applying updates via composer and wpackagist.

To disable admins from performing updates (and getting our code out of sync), we add these to our config:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',   true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',   true);
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE',  false);
```

This works great ... except that we no longer get the badges to show us that there *are* updates available.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to have the sidebar show the update icons (like the image on the left instead of the right), and/or the `/wp-admin/update-core.php` to display what updates are available ... but just not let admins *perform* the updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you also mentioned, Disable Updates using

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',   true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',   true);
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE',  false);
```

And, add another pseudo dashboard page. This will also enable you to show your custom messages to user in case users click this menu.

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wp_24392446' );
function wp_24392446() {
    $count = count( get_core_updates() ) + count( get_theme_updates() ) + count( get_plugin_updates() );
    $notification = '';
    if ( $count ) {
        $notification = '<span class="update-plugins"><span class="plugin-count">'.$count.'</span></span>';
    }
    add_dashboard_page( 'Updates', 'Updates '.$notification, 'user_cap_here', 'updates', 'updates', '',71); 
}

function updates(){
    // DO your stuff here
    // eg: echo 'Updates are currenlty disabled.'
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ... although I was secretly hoping for some cut-and-paste code instead of "set count here dynamically".  ;)  Are there some WP functions I can hook into to get a list of which plug-ins require updates?

Comment: @Colin I've updated my answer. Now you can use it as Plug n Play. :)

Comment: It'll count updates available for Wordpress, Plugin & Themes as well. Use it as a Plugin or Add it in your function.php. It'll start working.

Comment: I needed to tweak things a bit, but yes this got me on the right track.  Thanks!